# Array Index out of Bound Exception for returning Char Array

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming and I was writing code to replace spaces in Strings with `%20` and return the final String. Here is the code for the problem. Since I am new to programming please tell me what I did wrong. Sorry for my bad English.

```
package Chapter1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Problem4 {
public  char[] replaceSpaces(char[] str_array, int length)
{
    int noOfSpaces=0,i,newLength;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(str_array[i]==' ')
        {
            noOfSpaces++;
        }

        newLength = length + noOfSpaces * 2;
        str_array[newLength]='\0';
        for(i=0;i<length-1;i++)
        {
            if(str_array[i]==' ')
            {
                str_array[newLength-1]='0';
                str_array[newLength-2]='2';
                str_array[newLength-3]='%';
                newLength = newLength-3;
            }
            str_array[newLength-1]=str_array[i];
            newLength = newLength - 1;

        }
    }

    return str_array;

}
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please enter the string:");
    String str = reader.readLine();
    char[] str_array = str.toCharArray();
    int length = str.length();
    Problem4 obj = new Problem4();
    char[] result = obj.replaceSpaces(str_array, length);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Please enter the string:
hello world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
at Chapter1.Problem4.replaceSpaces(Problem4.java:19)
at Chapter1.Problem4.main(Problem4.java:46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java arrays are not dynamic (they are `Object` instances, and they have a field `length` property that does not change). Because they store the length as a field, it is important to know that they're not `'\0'` terminated (your attempt to add such a terminator is causing your index out of bounds `Exception`). Your method doesn't appear to access any instance fields or methods, so I'd make it static. Then you could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like

```
public static char[] replaceSpaces(char[] str_array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : str_array) {
        sb.append((ch != ' ') ? ch : "%20");
    }
    return sb.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Then call it like

```
char[] result = replaceSpaces(str_array);
```

Finally, you might use `String str = reader.readLine().replace(" ", "+");` or `replaceAll(" ", "%20")` as suggested by [@Arvind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2575725/arvind) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059943/2970947).

P.S. When you finally get your `result` you'll need to fix your call to `print` it.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

or

```
System.out.println(new String(result));
```

A `char[]` is not a `String` and Java arrays (disappointingly) don't override `toString()` so you'll get the one from `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `String.replaceAll()`:

```
String str = reader.readLine();
str = str.replaceAll(" ", "02%");
```

Sample [code here](https://ideone.com/LOPTp9)

**EDIT**:

The problem is at line 19:

```
str_array[newLength]='\0';//<-- newLength exceeds the char array size
```

Here array is static i.e. the size is fixed you can use `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, etc to build the new String without worrying about the size for such small operations.

Comment: Should be "%20" (or `+`), it's a URL encoded space.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to see what mistakes you made when implementing your approach, instead of looking for a totally different approach:

(1) As has been pointed out, once an array has been allocated, its size cannot be changed.  Your method takes `str_array` as a parameter, but the resulting array will likely be larger than `str_array`.  Therefore, since `str_array`'s length cannot be changed, you'll need to allocate a new array to hold the result, rather than using `str_array`.  You've computed `newLength` correctly; allocate a new array of that size:

```
char[] resultArray = new char[newLength];
```

(2) As Elliott pointed out, Java strings don't need `\0` terminators.  If, for some reason, you really want to create an array that has a `\0` character at the end, then you have to add 1 to your computed `newLength` to account for the extra character.

(3) You're actually creating the resulting array backward.  I don't know if that is intentional.

```
        if(str_array[i]==' ')
        {
            str_array[newLength-1]='0';
            str_array[newLength-2]='2';
            str_array[newLength-3]='%';
            newLength = newLength-3;
        }
        str_array[newLength-1]=str_array[i];
        newLength = newLength - 1;
```

`i` starts with the first character of the string and goes upward; you're filling in characters starting with the last character of the string (`newLength`) and going backward.  If that's what you intended to do, it wasn't clear from your question.  Did you want the output to be `"dlrow%20olleh"`?

(4) If you *did* intend to go backward, then what the above code does with a space is to put `%20` in the string (backwards), *but then it also puts the space into the result*.  If the input character is a space, you want to make sure you don't execute the two lines that copy the input character to the result.  So you'll need to add an `else`.  (Note that this problem will lead to an out-of-bounds error, because you're trying to put more characters into the result than you computed.)  You'll need to have an `else` in there even if you really meant to build the string forwards and need to change the logic to make it go forward.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised in this line `str_array[newLength]='\0';` because value of  `newLength` is greater than length of `str_array`.

Array size cannot be increased once it is defined. So try the alternative solution.

```
 char[] str_array1=Arrays.copyOf(str_array, str_array.length+1);
 str_array1[newLength]='\0';
```

don't forget to import the new package `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: so how do i make the length of my array greater than newLength?

Comment: arraysize could not not increased once it is defined, so the alternative solution is you could declare a new array with the size increased by 1 of the old array. Here is the example.

 char[] str_array1=Arrays.copyOf(str_array, str_array.length+1);
 str_array1[newLength]='\0';

Comment: @Karthikeyan Now you're null terminating arrays in Java? It's not a pointer!

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Of course it's a not a pointer. I am just creating new array with the size increased by 1 of the old array and appending an value .

Answer (score 0):

> please tell me what I did wrong

You tried to replace a single character  with three characters `%20`. That's not possible because arrays are fixed length.

Therefore you must allocate a new `char[]` and copy the characters from str_array into the new array.

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (str_array[i] == ' ') {
        noOfSpaces++;
    }
}

newLength = length + noOfSpaces * 2;
char[] newArray = new char[newLength];
// copy characters from str_array into newArray
```